# How to remove focus from List view and set focus behind layout of List View.

Tags: android, android-layout

I have ListView and button.when I click on button.It should slide from top to bottom and when I again press button it again slide bottom to top.I have another layout behind the list when slide i will be able to see another layout but i'm unable to focus on that layout.I am using a animation to list.I have used two xml's in anim folder.

```
I happily able to slide but I'm unable to get focus to behind view of listview 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        slide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sliding);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buuton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        ssss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buuton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ssss.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ssp);
        list.setAdapter(aa);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

slide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
                Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);

                if (slidestatus == false) {

                    list.startAnimation(slideDown);
                    slidestatus = true;
                } else {
                    list.startAnimation(slideUp);
                    slidestatus = false;
                }
            }
        });

 and my main xml 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sanjeev.loginfrom.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOGIN FORM" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sliding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="slide" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_sliding"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_sliding"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_sliding"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_sliding"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

How can i get focus to views behind the list view.
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:id="@+id/relative_layout"` to RelativeLayot in xml file.
Now from Activity get RelativeLayout and focus on, like below:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
relativeLayout.requestFocus();
```

you can focus on wherever you want.

Comment: My point is that you can get your parent groupView and focus on. Just add id on your LinearLayout/RelativeLayout.

Comment: I am able to wirte the text into editext but i cannot have focus onto the buttons

Comment: I'm unable to set focus